# Local Ajax request / Sencha / PhoneGap on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, extjs

I am trying to load some content in a PhoneGap App via a local Ajax request. It seems to work fine on iPhone, but Android wont find the file.

It goes like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'file:///android_asset/webapp/content/file.html',
        success: function(response, opts) {
            console.log('response ' + response.responseText);
        }
        failure: function(response, opts) {
            console.log('response ' + response.responseText);
        }
    });
```

I already adjusted the Manifest and did set the Internet Permission, still no success.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Web browsers don't allow local files to be accessed to ensure better security.  [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Mozilla]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I do in situations like this is to get rid of the dependency on third party libraries like Sencha or jQuery and go straight to use XHR. There is an issue where making requests from file protocol sometimes returns a status of 0 when it actually is 200. Most libraries have this fixed but you never know. Try this XHR code which should work just great on Android:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "file:///android_asset/webapp/content/file.html", true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
                console.log("response " + request.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    request.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this totally meets your requirements but have a look at this [Phonegap Android plugin](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android) collection. It includes plugins for [uploading](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/FileUploader) and [downloading](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Downloader) content for PhoneGap on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Sencha Touch are you using? As Simon pointed out, many libs report a failure when encountering a response code of 0, Sencha Touch fixed this as of 2.0.0

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?173577-Ext.data.Connection-fails-when-evaluating-a-file-protocol-s-status

Second, try removing the file:///android_asset/webapp/ part of the ULR, a relative url to your content directory should work just fine, and alleviate any OS detection switching you might be doing to arrive at that path.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'content/file.html',
    success: function(response, opts) {
        console.log('response ' + response.responseText);
    }
    failure: function(response, opts) {
        console.log('response ' + response.responseText);
    }
});
```