# PhoneGap load local page inside HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I tried to load a page inside my **phonegape aplication** with Jquery `.load()` but it doesn't work since it's not on a server and it's on local machine. When I'll upload the app on build. phonegape my  page will still be included on the `www` folder. How can I load a page inside a div ?
This is not working

```
<script>

  $(".form-control2").change(function(){


    $(".plan_mese4").load("select_mese.html");

});
</script>
```

If I use `http` it's working but i don't need that since my file is local and not on a server.

edit*

Right now i have my app on desktop, i also compiled it with phonegap and .load() it's not working since the file is local. It only works if i put my file on a server and i load it from there but i don't want that since the request take more time.

Comment: here is a trick, via ajax, get that data in html format and load that on particular div. :)

Comment: @ShivamPandya — That's not a trick, that's the **problem**. `load` uses Ajax!

Comment: I'm not clear about what the problem is. Are you saying that it doesn't work when you use a desktop web browser? That's expected behaviour because of normal security restrictions on local HTML files (and not a real problem because that isn't your target platform). Are you saying it doesn't work when you compile it with PhoneGap and then install the resulting application on a mobile device?

Comment: @Quentin thanks for pointing out my mistake :)

Comment: yes right now i have my app on desktop, i also compiled it with phonegap and .load() it's not working since the file is local. It only works if i put my file on a server and i load it from there but i don't want that since the request take more time.

Comment: @chris227 — So it doesn't work when you compile the app and load it onto the device?

Comment: yes `.load()` function does nothing

Comment: Possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813013/local-ajax-request-sencha-phonegap-on-android

Answer (score 0):

thnx to Quentin i found that i can use the filepath to make an ajax call even if it's local. So i did it like this if anyone else needs it. I get the url location in my case `file:///E:/rezerv.city/www/local.html?id=114&tip=5`and i remove the  `local.html?id=114&tip=5.html` part and i add what i need in my case select_mese.html.

```
$(".form-control2").change(function(){

            var url =window.location.href;
            url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            $(".plan_mese4").load(url +'index.html');


});
```

Answer (score 0):

in my app I'm use:

```
<div id="loadExternalURL" class="site"></div>

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
 $('#loadExternalURL').load('http://www.site.com.br');

$.ajax({
  dataType:'html',
  url:'http://www.site.com.br',
  success:function(data) {
    $('#ajax').html($(data).children());
  }
  }); 
}
```

It works for me.